# 13.10 indicator-sound only preferred-media-players

Tags: 13.10, indicator-sound

My Ubuntu 13.10 ignores my settings for my media players:

[image: my desktop]

altough the dconf-editor settings are such, that there's only one preferred-media-player ('vlc.desktop') my indicator-sound shows gmusicbrowser, spotify and vlc (which are supposed to be "only" interested-media-players as preferred-media-players

The screenshot explains my problem...

why? and how can I change this?
I have no idea why this happens

Comment: What is the intention here?

Comment: edited my question, sorry if it was unclear

Comment: @user1943296 So you want all the 3 players to be present in the list, but only vlc should have sound controls? Or you want only vlc in the list?

Comment: exactly! only vlc should have the controls... I know sounds stupid, but I wonder why it doesn't work

Comment: @user1943296 Are you sure that gmusicbrowser and spotify not running in the background? `ps aux` doesn't list them?

Comment: well it does; kind of: `ps aux | grep gmusicbrowser` gives `andreas   7915  0.0  0.0  15172   956 pts/4    S+   17:23   0:00 grep --color=auto gmusicbrowser`

Comment: but this is probably just the grep command itself

Comment: Yes, it just shows your greping process, but gmusicbrowser is not running) I would say that this is a bug, and you should file a bugreport [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sound), but I'm not on 13.10 so I don't really know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it is not a bug. I found it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sound/+bug/1213907) . If I understand correctly this is the designed behaviour:

> Is this bug about having the players in the menu at all, or about that each player item is showing playback widgets?
>
> If it is the latter, I agree that this is a bit weird, but it is in accordance with the current sound menu spec: "The playback item should be present if the player can be controlled externally (CanControl)."

Read on that bugreport for some more info. Also looks like that "bug" is in *Triaged* status so things may change in the future.

Comment: thanks. At least I'm not the only one who finds this awful...

Answer (score 0):

Long way, Disable MPRIS DBus interface from non needed players to be in the sound menu.

- gmusicbrowser:

  Settings → Plugins → Uncheck `MPRIS v2` & `MPRIS v1`
- Video Player (`totem`):

  Edit → Plugins... → Uncheck `D-Bus Service`
- VLC 2.0.x

  Tools → Preferences → Advanced (or All) → Interface → Control Interfaces → D-Bus control interface. :

  VLC 2.1.x see [Remove VLC player from sound menu in Unity bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468811/remove-vlc-player-from-sound-menu-in-unity-bar)
- Rhythmbox:

  Tools → Plugins... → Uncheck `MPRIS D-Bus Interface`
- Gnome MPlayer: Hardcoded